# Fill shape with no-repeat image pattern: unwanted contour line

Tags: svg, shapes, fill

In my Angular application, the user can insert an image into an SVG shape and apply a transform to the image interactively. By default, the image fills the shape.

It works well, except for one very annoying problem which occurs when:

- The shape has no stroke
- One side of the image is much darker than the opposite side

When these conditions are met, a very thin line appears on the side of the shape where the image is lighter. For example, if the bottom of the image is much darker than the top, the thin line will appear at the top of the shape. That line comes from the opposite side of the image, as if the pattern is trying to repeat. I know that there is nothing like a `no-repeat` attribute for image patterns, so I set the following pattern attributes to avoid repeating:

```
<pattern patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" ...>
```

It works but not perfectly. The thin line is not always visible on the screen, even when zooming, but it is most of the time. It causes us problems since these SVG shapes are part of book pages, and the thin line often ends up being visible in the final print.

Is there a good way to completely avoid pattern repeating? I tried extending the pattern so that it overflows the shape, but the extra size has to be somewhat significant to be effective:

```
<pattern x="-0.01" y="-0.01" width="1.02" height="1.02" ...>
```

When I run the code snippet below in my Chrome browser, the unwanted thin blue line is visible at the top of the shape. The problem is not specific to Chrome however; I see it on Firefox as well.

```html
<div style="padding: 20px; width: 180px; height: 150px; background-color: yellow;">
  <svg height="100%" width="100%" x="0%" y="0%" viewBox="0 0 1600 1200">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" 
        width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 1600 1200">
        <image width="1600" height="1200" x="0" y="0" 
          xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/vZ9spGH/1600x1200-1.png"></image>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url('#pattern1')" height="100%" width="100%" x="0%" y="0%"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: But a pattern is just made to repeat its content, so why don't you just use the plain image, since it should not be repeated?

Comment: @philipp - Can I include a plain image inside of a shape? I show a simple case in the question but the shape can be any kind of path, and it can have a stroke.

Comment: If the whole point is having the image cropped to a shape, use a [`<clipPath>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#ClipPathElement), probably with `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and the size of the shape normalized to 1.

Comment: In regard to your question, does setting `style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision"` on the rect have any effect?

Comment: @ccprog - I tried setting the `shape-rendering` style/attribute and the thin repeat line is still there. To explain the feature: each SVG element is a frame in which the user can insert a picture; one specific shape being set as the image container. The user can interactively: insert the picture, change the stroke thickness of the shape, move, resize and rotate the frame, move, resize and rotate the picture inside of the frame. That is why having the image inside of the shape appeared natural to me. The `preserveAspectRatio` pattern attribute is also convenient for scaling.

Comment: All that can also be achieved the other way around - for the stroke around the shape, a `<use>` element referencing the clipPath content will do the trick.

Comment: @ccprog - I am sure that it can be done but it appears less natural and more trouble than having the image inside of the shape. Before going that route, I will wait to see if someone has a suggestion on how to implement a completely successful `no-repeat` pattern. It already works at 99.9%...

Answer (score 1):

Shape fills are fairly straightforward using a filter:

```html
<div style="padding: 20px; width: 180px; height: 150px; background-color: yellow;">
  <svg height="100%" width="100%" x="0%" y="0%" viewBox="0 0 1600 1200">
    <defs>
      <filter id="simple-image-fill" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
      
        <feImage width="1600" height="1200" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
          xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/vZ9spGH/1600x1200-1.png" result="image-res"/>
          <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" in="image-res"/>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect filter="url(#simple-image-fill)" height="100%" width="100%" x="0%" y="0%"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks very promising. Thanks! I cannot fully test it right now but I will as soon as I can.

Comment: The filter overwrites the stroke when there is one, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. There is a technique that you can use to retain the stroke, but it gets a bit complicated and would need a filter specific to each stroke color.

Comment: That is unfortunate. What I don't understand, is why SVG patterns don't have a `no-repeat` option. Especially since using a pattern is the only way to include an image in a shape (AFAIK). The use case where repetition is not desired must not be so exceptional.

Comment: You can also try shifting the start position of your pattern up a little - that seems to erase the bug: width="1" height="1.01" x="0" y="-0.01" viewBox="0 0 1600 1200"